Why do I need to type ggVVG to select all, instead of just ggVG?
Sometimes, ggVG does not work to select text. It will move the cursor to the top, but not select the text. This happens seemingly randomly. I have figured out if I type ggVVG it will work as expected. I can also retype ggVG many times and it will work eventually after 4-10 tries.

do you potentially type gggV? so accidentally using gV instead of V?

Are there mappings on V? :verbose map V

@D.BenKnoble There aren't any mappings on V. ("No mapping found")

@ChristianBrabandt I think that's it! I am able to replicate the behavior and it makes sense why it was happening seemingly randomly. Why does this happen? My cursor doesn't move when I press the third g, and it seems like odd-numbered "g" presses undo the ability to enter visual mode in one button press.

Make sure to not accidentally typing gggVG, so after gg (to go to the top), another g, which in turn changes your V command to a gV command (see :help gV), which basically is a no-op in your case and this would explain why your V command randomly does not appear to work.
BTW: depending on your use case for the ggVG command, it might be easier to use an ex-command. I assume you want to copy the whole buffer text, which I think :%y find much easier (for yank all lines).
